# jquery, change content on a popup

Tags: jquery, popup

I have a simple page (index.html) with a div:

I am populating that div with some easy jquery commands:

```
$("#email").html("someemail@email.com");
```

Is there a way to populate a similar div on a popup?   I like to use popups for debugging reasons, but I don't want to reload the popup each time the main page refreshes.

In other words, can jquery search for an element on a different window?

It's a long shot, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: What do you mean by a "popup"?  There is no such HTML element.  There are many ways to implement a popup window.  To answer this question, we'd need to know which you are using.

Comment: @James: he meant popup window. was that so obscure?

Comment: I'm referring to a popup window.  Or maybe just a different page.

My question is, can jquery change elements in a popup, or change elements on a different page?   I don't want to create a popup with jquery.
Just change things on the popup, but from a completely different window.

Example:

Page1.html has a button that say "Update Page2"

Page2.html has a div that gets populated with anything you want.
(when you click the button on page1.html, the div on page2.html gets updated with something you want.)

Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Rakesh -- Please re-read my original comment, paying special attention to the third and fourth sentences.

Comment: If this is just for debugging purposes I would suggest using FireBug to trace out your code's execution. It will make your life 1000 times better than trying to use floating divs or popups.

Comment: @James: Oops, i overlooked tht :x

Comment: For debugging, try Blackbird 'http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to launch a separate browser, loading a separate webpage, to display more information.  ???

DO NOT DO THAT  !!

It's slow, and most users find it rather annoying.  So annoying, that nearly everyone of them will be using some form of popup blocker, which you are now expecting them to disable, just to see some content on your page.  Most will find this *extremely* annoying.

Since you are already using jQuery, why not just use [jQuery UI's Dialog plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  This turns a hidden DIV on you page into a popup.  It's looks better than an old-fashioned popup, runs faster, and since it's part of your same page, solve the problem you are asking about..

UPDATE:  Sorry about the rant -- I didn't see the comment about using this for debugging purposes -- but really, using a popup for debugging is a even worse idea, even if you are the only one being annoyed.   (have you considered `alert()` )

Comment: I actually wrote a dialogue box opener, but after using it for a while, reverted back to a separate popup window because there are so many more advantages to using a separate popup. Popups, by the way, are ok when the user initiates them with a button or some call to action.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just about debugging i will not recommend a popup for that. You can go for `blackbird` [http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/] or `firebug console [`console.log ( 'blah blah' )`]`

Otherwise you can check out
http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/

and at last, if you just want to stick to *popups*, this might help you

http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html

Comment: Ah...Blackbird... That was the one I was going to recommend --- except that I forgot it's name....

Comment: I think the bigger question here isn't about how to debug, but how to replace content in a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really what you're asking, but I think it's a near-substitute.

In Firefox it's possible to use Firebug (Opera has Dragonfly, and Chrome has its developer tools) and, from jQuery, use:

```
console.log("message to display in the console, plus: " + variable_names)
```

to display debug messages. These `console.log()` commands will cause js errors when the console is not active, though.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, no, it's not possible as far as I know.

What you CAN do, is read the content from the popoup window, though.

```
var popup = window.open('url', 'params');
var dom = popup.document.body;
for(i in dom){
    console.log(dom[i]);
}
```

You can't, however, change the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very late but how about log4javascript.

It is fantastic

http://log4javascript.org/